# Reference Div instead of Window for Scroll Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable div, and I am trying to change the opacity of a div within it on scroll with the following jquery code. However, I think its not working being its referencing the browser window i think. I was wondering how i can reference the container, which has the class .container.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).scroll(function(){
            var top=$(this).scrollTop();
            if(top<150){
                var dif=1-top/150;
                $(".text-beginning").css({opacity:dif});
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: It's referencing the `document` scrollTop, you'll need to adjust this to the scrollable element if the document isn't scrolling.

Comment: would i replace document with the . class name of the container?

Answer (score 0):

This demo works:

jsfiddle.net/zvt3e/

See if there is any difference in your situation.

Comment: i dont think its working because i have three seperate containers with in the document. and that class its referencing is only in one of those containers.

Comment: I think it will be easier if you can provide the html, you can put it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: sure something like this http://jsfiddle.net/wg3X4/ , I want the header to fade out by changing in opacity. I also wanted try to adjust other attributes of the header that would fade at the same time like a new background color or a font color.

Comment: Your demo is using wrong selector, which should be  $(".articles-container-item-top").css({opacity:dif}); You just miss the '.'. FYI, you should select a jquery version on the left column to run your jquery methods.